Is it possible under Windows to rewrite the USB product ID, or to process data from a USB device and output it as a different one?
I found this project which outputs USB data from an Arduino module, spoofing/acting as a SpaceMouse and it is recognised by the official drivers.
Using Windows how can I read the data output by my SpacePilot (a much older device, conceptually identical in features, and not supported anymore) and convert it to the newer format, so that newer drivers can make use of it?
The latest drivers I can use lack features now required for modern software.
